# Enable WSUS targeting using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, wsus

I need a PowerShell script to enable client side targeting and set a target group name for the computer by changing this registry key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
"TargetGroup"="<CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME>;<SUBGROUPNAME>"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Server Fault is not a script writing service. However, you need to get some things clear first...

> I need ... to enable client side targeting.

If you have a Windows AD Domain, use Group Policy instead. It's much more maintainable, because you won't need to run your script on every computer, but just move it to the correct OU.

```
Computer Configuration 
 |- Administrative Templates
  |- Windows Components
   |- Windows Update
```

has a policy [Enable client-side targetting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-server-update-services/deploy/4-configure-group-policy-settings-for-automatic-updates#BKMK_comp9) you can use for setting the group.

> I need a power shell script ...

This would be a very basic PowerShell script for setting two to four registry keys: Setting the **`TargetGroup` alone doesn't enable the targeting; `TargetGroupEnabled` does**. You also need to specify the WSUS server in keys for both getting the updates and reporting the updates applied.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
"WUServer"="https://wsusserver.example.com"
"WUStatusServer"="https://wsusserver.example.com"
"TargetGroup"="TargetGroupName"
"TargetGroupEnabled"=dword:00000001
```

Now you are ready to write the script for [Updating or Adding Registry Key Value with PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/04/02/update-or-add-registry-key-value-with-powershell/). Here's the script from the article, modified to update `TargetGroupEnabled`. Rest is homework.

```
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate"
$Name = "TargetGroupEnabled"
$value = "1"

IF(!(Test-Path $registryPath))
{
    New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force | Out-Null
    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value `
        -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
}
ELSE
{
    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value `
        -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: Thank You.The above registry changes are done for all entry through powershell and values are updated, But unable to see the changes under GP Edit > Windows Update. Even after restart of services and gpupdate. Could you please guide.